# Mordell Weil group (and other elliptic curves) computations using SageMath(jupyter or offline version)

Tags: elliptic-curves, sagemath

I apologise in advance if the question of this sort is not appropriate for this site.

I am new to SageMath and have been exploring computations related to elliptic curves with it, this hasn't been a difficult thing to do as you have to just copy the commands from the internet. But a few days ago, I came across this : https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.10415

On page 68 here, the author has done some computations using SageMath and got things like blinds on the rank of quotients $E(\mathbb{Q})/\hat{\phi}(E'(\mathbb{Q}))$, $E(\mathbb{Q})/2E(\mathbb{Q})$, Selmer groups, etc.

My question is, how do I do the same? I am familiar with the two_descent but it only tells you whether two-descent can be done for an elliptic curve or not and certainly is not as elaborative as the one used by the author in this pdf.

I haven't been able to find any manuals online either that begin to explain this, plus I don't know anyone in real life who's familiar with it. So I'd appreciate it if someone here could help me out.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Page 68 contains something else. (Some code and 9.0.2. Cremona tables.) Please specify an explicit example and what should be done for it. (Sage can easily compute the rank in case of elliptic curves decently small coefficients in the equation. Proposition 6.4 is an in between human step, things a human can try first to figure out the rank.) Also, writing code needs some example(s) of curve(s). The complexity of the situation and the code depend on a fixed example. Please specify one or more curves and what should be computed for them.

Comment: you may wish to try asking this at ask.sagemath.org